# how to fix "Syntax Highlighting is too slow"？

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use C++, and after a version update syntax highlighting became slow, always delaying colors by a few seconds.I just used the vscode-cpptools extension。

No Settings can be found

For example, when I comment with "//", some of the following characters take a few seconds to turn green.

Normal should be immediately green, at least previous vscode versions are normal.

Comment: Looks like this issue is still open and they're working on this., see the open issue about this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/64681

Comment: @ahmedaljubair  I don't think so. I encountered this problem after a version update in June 2019, not last December.

Comment: That's what I told you. The issue is "open" & also as you can see it was added to the backlog which is, as of this date, only 68% completed. Means, it was just posted in December but it's still not closed so they're still working on it - they haven't fixed it yet

Comment: Reference link to the progress of the backlogs: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/milestone/8

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue for a while, but I fixed it by resetting all the settings and then importing another syntax highlight setting that I downloaded from the web:

`Tools -> Import & Export settings -> Reset all settings`

Then do an import of a new `syntax highlight settings`